# How to forward touch events to underlaying elements in android

Tags: android, webview, touch

I have a WebView and an element under the webview.
Now everytime the user touches the webview, the touch should be forwarded to the underlying element. So the webView should just be a screenshot where you can "click through", no scrolling etc.

If I do it like this:

```
        myWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

I can intercept the touches and the webView gets unclickable, but the touches get "lost", because everyone else thinks, that the webView already handled them.

Please answer me in an easy way, because I am new to android development.

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried returning `false` instead?

Comment: yes, I have. The webView gets scroll- and clickable. I also tried myWebView.setClickable(false); and myWebView.setFocusable(false); but it didn't work

Comment: have you seen [this guide](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html) on handling touch events in ViewGroups? You probably don't want to create your own ViewGroup, but it might give you some ideas.

Comment: Have you tried passing the behind-view the touch event via .onTouchEvent(event) from your WebView's OnTouchListener? E.g. public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            behindView.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        } Also note, the local coordinates of the event passed (i.e. event.getX()) may not match up to your behind-view, so, when processing the events in the behind view, you may want to use event.getRawX() to get the event's location on the screen (as opposed to its location inside the View), and then convert it to local coordinates of the behind-view